# What is the performance penalty of chaining USB hubs?

Tags: usb, performance, usb-hub

USB hubs with lots of ports (7 or 10) often consist of chained 4-port hubs. I wonder how good the performance of the various ports of those hubs is.

Specifically I'm thinking about mass storage devices (i.e. high throughput+latency, 480M or 5G, enough to potentially saturate the bus) and MIDI/HID devices (i.e. low latency+throughput, 12M or 480M) both connected to the same hub.

I assume 12M performance could be better if each 12M device is plugged into a different hub and thus gets its own TT? And everything else is probably worse, but how much?

Comment: I have used USB Hubs like you described for years, connected to multiple external USB 3 HDDs, and have never had a performance problem.  I had to be careful to always use short USB extender cables so I never exceeded the recommended length, otherwise Windows would report there wasn't enough resources, but that had nothing to do with the number of ports the HUbs offered though.

Comment: @Ramhound Interesting. The reason I ask this question is because I've precisely got performance problems including such a hub, but I don't really know whether the hub is the problem, or the CPU (it's... not terribly fast).

Comment: This is an externally powered HUB?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. It has a 60W power supply. Should be plenty for 4 2.5" disks and some peripherals.